# Elasticsearch : using fuzzy search to find abbreviations

Tags: elasticsearch, similarity, fuzzy-search

I have indexed textual articles which mentions company names, like `apple` and `lemonade`, and am trying to search for these companies using their abbreviations like `APPL` and `LMND` but fuzzy search is giving other results, for example, searching with `LMND` gives `land` which is mentioned in the text but it doesn't output `lemonade` whichever parameters I tried.

**First question**
Is fuzzy search the suitable solution for such search ?

**Second question**

what could be a good parameter values ranges to support my problem ?

**UPDATE**

I have tried synonym filter

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "synonyms_filter": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [
              "apple,APPL",
              "lemonade,LMND"
            ]
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "synonym_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "synonyms_filter"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "transcript_data": {
        "properties": {
          "words": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "word": {
                "type": "text",
                "search_analyzer":"synonym_analyzer"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and for **SEARCH** I used

```
{
  "_source": false,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "transcript_data.words",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "transcript_data.words.word": "lmnd"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the best option for you is the use of synonyms, they serve exactly what you need.

I'll leave an example and the [link](https://www.elastic.co/blog/boosting-the-power-of-elasticsearch-with-synonyms) to an article explaining some details.

```
PUT teste
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "synonyms_filter": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [
              "apple,APPL",
              "lemonade,LMND"
            ]
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "synonym_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "synonyms_filter"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "transcript_data": {
        "properties": {
          "words": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "word": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer":"synonym_analyzer"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST teste/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"transcript_data": {"words":{"word":"apple"}}}


GET teste/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "transcript_data.words",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "transcript_data.words.word": "appl"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please check edits

Comment: replace "search_analyzer":"synonym_analyzer" with "analyzer": "synonym_analyzer". The difference is that it will also index the synonymous terms but your search will work.
I'll try to understand why the search_analizer didn't work with nested objects

Comment: I tried that, but it won't work too

Comment: I had to set it manually in the query to make it work

Comment: Strange, here it worked. I removed the source=false, why do you use it like that? I updated my answer.

Comment: am basically interested in `inner hits`